# How to send an array of variables from an env.yml to serverless.yml?

Tags: arrays, yaml, serverless-framework

I have an `env.yml` file where I store some variables that should be be sent to the `serverless.yml`. I want to send this array of variables from the `env.yml` to the `serverless.yml`.

This. is what I have in the `env.yml`

```
securityGroupIds:[sg-xxx]
subnetIds: [subnet-xx1, subnet-xx2, subnet-xx3, subnet-xx4]
```

This is what I have in the `serverless.yml`:

```
vpc:
      securityGroupIds: ${file(env.yml):securityGroupIds}
      subnetIds: ${file(env.yml):securityGroupIds}
```

And this is what I was expecting to get inside `serverless.yml` when I `sls print --stage dev`:

```
vpc:
      securityGroupIds:
        - sg-xxx
      subnetIds:
        - subnet-xx1
        - subnet-xx2
        - subnet-xx3
        - subnet-xx4
```

It is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I have found the way:

in the `env.yml`:

```
vpc-dev: {
  "securityGroupIds": [
      "sg-xxx"
  ],
  "subnetIds": [
      "subnet-xx1",
      "subnet-xx2",
      "subnet-xx3",
      "subnet-xx4"
  ]
}

vpc-prod: {
  "securityGroupIds": [
      "sg-xxxy"
  ],
  "subnetIds": [
      "subnet-xx1y",
      "subnet-xx2y",
      "subnet-xx3y",
      "subnet-xx4y"
  ]
}
```

in the serverless.yml

```
function
  hello: ...
  handler: ...
  ...  
  vpc: ${file(env.yml):vpc-${self:provider.stage}}
```